# "Ghost" div appearing in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I got a fixed element placed 50px from the top and left. When the page loads, I get this wierd "ghost" of the div a bit underneath it, and I can't figure out why it shows up. It doesn't show up in neither Edge nor Chrome, just Firefox, and as soon as I interact with the page (click it, scroll, open the inspect tool), it vanishes. Any idea why it's appearing in the first place, and only in Firefox?

I'm using a jQuery plugin called onepage-scroll.js, if that might have anything to do with this.

Here's an image of the top left corner of my page, with the "ghost" appearing. [image]

Comment: I see no way to answer without the markup/css details here.

Comment: Well the answer is obviously î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: I pasted the relevant html, css and jquery into a pen, but the "ghost" doesn't show up here, so I'm gussing it has something to do with the plugin?

http://codepen.io/hrve/pen/RpmJNR